# Redirect to shop page if the cart is empty when removing cart item using ajax in Woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I want to redirect the cart page to the shop page when cart is empty. Cart item remove using ajax so after all item removed than I will redirect to shop page without refresh the page.

Here is the code I have tried, but it does not work:

```
function cartitem_after_remove_product($cart_item_key) {
    global $woocommerce;
     $total_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
     if($total_count == 0)
     {
         wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
     }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'cartitem_after_remove_product' );
```

Comment: But you said that you used ajax to remove the items from Cart.

Comment: @Ranjit yes.. i used ajax for removing the cart items. so what?

Comment: you can check the cart at the return and redirect to home url

Comment: removing cart item using ajax is done by woocommerce function. so how to check cart is empty and redirect to shop page